# Async/await again: Where to put await and return?

Tags: node.js, typescript, vscode-extensions

In a VSCode extension I have a function that removes certain directories from the current workspace. But the function does not wait for the directories to be removed.

[The accepted answer for this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) makes sense, but still I can't figure out how to make my function work correctly. Where do I put await and return?

```
async function cleanUpWorkspace(workspace: any) {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const rimraf = require("rimraf");
    var targetFolders = ['dirA', 'dirB', 'dirC', 'dirD'];

    try {
        await targetFolders.forEach(function (value) { //'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.
            let targetPath = workspace + "\\\\" + value;
            if (fs.existsSync(targetPath)) {
                fs.promises.access(targetPath);
                rimraf(targetPath, function (err: any) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Directory: " + value + " was deleted");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log(value + " doesn't exist.");
            }
        });
        return Promise.resolve();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function prepare() {
    await cleanUpWorkspace(workspace);
}
```

- Typescript 4.3.5
- node.js 14.17.0

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return a promise, so it's useless to `await` it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can only use `await` inside an `async function` or an async arrow function (`async () => { /* function contents */ }`)
- You should only use `await` on functions that return a Promise
- All `async` functions, regardless of whether or not they `return` a value, return a `Promise`. If it doesn't return a value inside, the return type is `Promise<void>` (similar to how regular functions implicitly return `void` if they don't have a return value)

You are trying to do async operations (i.e call functions that return promises) inside the function passed to `forEach`. Ideally, we would `await` them. To use `await`, we need to make the function passed to `forEach` an `async` function. However, `forEach` does not internally `await` promises. This means that uncaught exceptions inside your `forEach` function do not make it up to the `try`/`catch` block.

To avoid this, we can use a `for..of` loop.

Because `async` functions automatically return a `Promise`, there's not really a reason you need to `return Promise.resolve()`

```
  try {
      for (const value of targetFolders) {
        let targetPath = workspace + "\\\\" + value;
        if (fs.existsSync(targetPath)) {
            await fs.promises.access(targetPath);
            rimraf(targetPath, function (err: any) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Directory: " + value + " was deleted");
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log(value + " doesn't exist.");
        }
      }
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
```

Now, we can `await` the `fs.promises.access` call.

---

Another thing we can do is promisify `rimraf`. There is a function in the Node standard library -- `util.promisify` -- that converts functions taking callbacks into functions returning promises. So, if we have

```
const util = require("util")
const rimrafPromise = util.promisify(rimraf)
```

then we can do

```
  try {
      for (const value of targetFolders) {
        let targetPath = workspace + "\\\\" + value;
        if (fs.existsSync(targetPath)) {
            await fs.promises.access(targetPath);
            await rimrafPromise(targetPath);
            console.log("Directory: " + value + " was deleted");
        } else {
            console.log(value + " doesn't exist.");
        }
      }
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
```